# header in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I'm programming my first socket lines, and have accomplish to make a client server system that transfer messages between. The next step is to make a header sow the receiver know how much data the message is and how the message is to. How can I accomplish this?

I want the header to contain two int:

```
int to_phone_number;
int size;
```

How can is send a header ?

```
send(sock, the_message, max_message_length, 0);
```

Comment: For reference, an `int` is not guaranteed to be big enough to represent a phone number (and in fact usually isn't, unless you assume phone numbers will never be over 9 digits long and `int`s have 32 bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header, body, it's still data.

You will send your header the same way you'd send anything.

You'd probably want to have a `struct message_header` that would compose your header.

```
struct message_header {
  int to_phone_number;
  int size;
};
```

Create a `struct message_header` variable, set its fields, then send it.

```
struct message_header header;
// ...
send(sock, &header, sizeof(header), 0);
```

Comment: The endian (byte ordering) between different systems may be different, and this should be accounted for.  Traditionally binary integer values are sent in big endian  order, so the 16 bit number `265` would be sent as (hex) `01 00` rather than `00 01`.  x86 is little endian.  The <arpa/inet.h> or <netinet/in.h> header has function to switch to and from network byte ordering that work right regardless of the system.  Additionally `sizeof(int)` varies from system to system.  You can include <stdint.h> and use `int32_t` to be sure of the size.