# PHP Socket Header, translate some C code

Tags: php, sockets, header, struct

I need to create a PHP interface that speaks to a server using sockets.

One of the requirements is the following:

"The command that the servers listens to is passed in a variable length message format, the length of the message is determined by a fixed 8 byte header field. This header record is used to control the reading of message from the socket as no terminators or carriage returns are used to delimit commands."

I have an example in C, and I would like to translate it in PHP if possible:

```
/* Structure to define the header */

typedef struct
{
char msg_len[4];
char seq_num[4];
} SP_AIP_HEAD;

/* Structure to Hold IP message with structure header */
typedef struct
{
   SD_AIP_HEAD ip_header;
   char ip_buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]
} SD_IP_MESS;
```

Here, [header in socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208998/header-in-socket-programming) I noticed you need to send the header as you send anything. But how can i translate these [struct] to a PHP message to be sent via PHP sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look here: [php passing c struct data throught socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993762/php-passing-c-struct-data-throught-socket-programming)

This should probably answer most of your question.